# what happens in the backend when CTRL+Z and CTRL+Y is clicked in microsoft word?How is data retrieved back on the click of CTRL+Y?

Tags: ms-word, notepad++

Working with word doc or excel or notepad we observe that the click of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> deletes the data and click of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> returns back the data. I want to know how in the software this is being managed. Where does the data get stored and how is it retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Word (and the other applications probably handle it similarly) maintains "temp" and "scratch" files in the same folder as the document file. During editing, information such as the changes being made are tracked in these files in order to enable Undo/Redo.

Beyond that, this is proprietary information that Microsoft has not made public.

Comment: Thank you Cindy for your explanation. I was keen on understanding if the data is pushed onto stack and retrieved from there. Is it like two seperate threads running. Kindly let me know if you have any such information.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the technical details. But the behavior is certainly similar to that, as you can't "skip" Undo entries. I believe, however, the information is actually written to a file, not kept in memory.